# Listing jupyter notebook code in pdf from .ipynb file

Tags: python

I am doing my programs in jupyter notebooks and I want to list it into my pdf using listings package or some other.

I don't want to insert images of my notebook. How can I do it? I can able to insert python code and its corresponding output. But i found no way to insert notebook into pdf using notebook file.

Comment: There is https://nbsphinx.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.5/ which will allow you to integrate your notebook in to a [Sphinx](http://www.sphinx-doc.org) project. But I guess you don't know Sphinx else you would not have asked the question. From a sphinx project you can produce PDF output. (it will use the Pygmentize library to highlight the code like minted, but this is neither minted nor listings).

Comment: You could perhaps use `nbconvert` to turn the notebook into a Python script.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `jupyter nbconvert` in your terminal. Simply do

`jupyter nbconvert /path/jupyterscript.ipynb --to latex`

This way you will get a tex file with your Notebook.

You can also just download the notebook itself as tex or pdf via latex. Just go on file and you will find the option under Download as...